# SseEmitter does not work after update to spring-boot 3

Tags: java, kotlin

I have an application that tests another application with a set of data. When this test runs, it takes some time, so I used SseEmiter to display the progress.
After updating to spring-boot version 3.0.7 it stopped working.

## code example:

The first one is called EP which creates an instance of SseEmitter.

```
    fun testProgressStream(emitterId: String) = run {
        val sseEmitter = sseEmitters[emitterId] ?: SseEmitter(600000)
        sseEmitters[emitterId] = sseEmitter
        sseEmitter
    }
```

The second EP is called next, where the test is started and the method "send" is called during the test.

```
 @Transactional
    fun runTest(
        projectId: ProjectId,
        request: RunTestRequest,
        authentication: Authentication,
        token: String,
        emitterId: String
    ): RunTestResponse {
        val sseEmitter = sseEmitters[emitterId]
        var counter = 0
        var (dataSetId, env, clientId) = request
        val dataSet = dataSetService.getFull(dataSetId)
        val testName = createTestName(dataSet, projectId, env, clientId)
        val client = configDataService.getClient(projectId, env, clientId, token)
        val author: String = authentication.name
        val traceId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

        ponyFacade = ponyFactory.byEnv(env) ?: throw TestException("Could not found Pony instance")
        var sessionId = createPonySession(client, traceId)
        val test = findOrCreateTest(dataSet, env, clientId, projectId, author)
        val resultItems = mutableListOf<TestResultItem>()


        val testResult = TestResult(
            name = testName, test = test, executed = LocalDateTime.now(clock), executedBy = author, items = resultItems
        )

        sseEmitter?.send(SseEmitter.event().data("Starting test!!").name(SSE_TEST_MESSAGE))
        test.results.add(testResult)

        dataSet.items.forEachIndexed loop@{ index, item ->

            if (item.question.equals(NEW_SESSION_FLAG, true)) {

                sseEmitter?.send(SseEmitter.event().data("--------------------").name(SSE_TEST_MESSAGE).id(item.hashCode().toString()))
                sseEmitter?.send(SseEmitter.event().data("Creating new session").name(SSE_TEST_MESSAGE))

                //Thread.sleep(1000) //By pausing, we prevent problems with the number of requests for IBM services in short time
                sessionId = createPonySession(client, traceId)
                return@loop
            }

            sseEmitter?.send(
                SseEmitter.event()
                    .data(dataSet.items.filter { it.question != NEW_SESSION_FLAG }.size)
                    .name(SSE_TEST_SIZE_EVENT)
            )

            sseEmitter?.send(SseEmitter.event().data("Question: ${item.question}" ).name(SSE_TEST_MESSAGE))

            val messageResponse = testMessage(ponyFacade, client.apiKey, traceId, sessionId, item)
            resultItems.add(buildTestResultItem(testResult, item, messageResponse))

            sseEmitter?.send(
                SseEmitter.event()
                    .data(++counter)
                    .name(SSE_TEST_PROGRESS_EVENT)
            )

            request.keepSession.takeIf { !it && index != dataSet.items.lastIndex }?.let {
                sessionId = createPonySession(client, traceId)
            }
        }
        sseEmitter?.onTimeout {
            sseEmitters.remove(emitterId)
        }
        sseEmitter?.onCompletion {
            sseEmitters.remove(emitterId)
        }
        sseEmitter?.complete()

        val report = testResult.items.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }?.let {
            compareTestsService.compare(it)
        }
        val savedTestEntity = repository.save(test)

        return RunTestResponse(
            testResultId = savedTestEntity.results.last().id,
            testDatasetIntentConflicts = report?.testDatasetIntentConflicts,
            testDataSetResponseIdConflicts = report?.testDataSetResponseIdConflicts,
            testIntentsConfidenceConflicts = report?.testIntentsConfidenceConflicts
        )
    }
```

**Even if the test ends, no message will come through EP with SseEmitor.**

I don't have any errors in BE, nothing just happens.

FE App throws an error, here is the console script.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mseLc.png)

```
 const wrongValues = validate();
        let emitterId = uuidv4();
        var eventSource = new EventSource(`${window.location.origin}/tf/api/v1/tests/progress-stream?emitterId=${emitterId}`)

        // addEventListener version
        eventSource.addEventListener("error", (e) => {
            console.log("An error occurred while attempting to connect.", e.data);
        });

        eventSource.onmessage = (e) => {
            console.log(e)
        };

        eventSource.addEventListener("TEST_PROGRESS", (event) => {
            let progress = JSON.parse(event.data);
            setProgress(progress);
            if (progress === itemsSize) {
                eventSource.close();
                console.log("SSE closed");
            }
        });

        eventSource.addEventListener("TEST_SIZE", (event) => {
            let size = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log(`Test size: ${size}`);
            setItemsSize(size);
        });

        eventSource.onerror = (event) => {
            if (event.target.readyState === EventSource.CLOSED)
                console.log("SSE closed (" + event.target.readyState + ")");
            else
                console.log("connection error", event);
                eventSource.close()
        };

        eventSource.onopen = () => {
            console.log("connection opened");
        };
```

I tried a lot of things, I don't know what to describe here.

For example, I added sending a message to the EP to create an Emmiter. The message comes, but if I put Thread.sleep(1000) before the message, the message doesn't come.

How I need it to work: So that during the running test, the messages that I set up and in parts of the code go to FE in real time, alo with using Thread.sleep() in code.